# Validate form input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate 3 form inputs and based on this I want to display either a success page or a failure page. I must do this using JavaScript. I have this so far:

```
<script src="scripts/formvalidator.js"></script>
<form method = "post" onsubmit = "validateForm()" >

    <label><strong>Name:</strong></label>
    <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter first and last name" />            
<br>
<br>

    <label><strong>Email:</strong></label>
    <br>
        <input type="email" name="usremail" placeholder="hello@wavemedia.ie" />
<br>
<br>
<!-- comment box -->
    <legend><strong>Your Message</strong></legend>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="10" cols="50">
        </textarea>
<div id="buttons"> 
<!-- buttons -->
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" value="Send"  style="margin-left:100px;">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"  style="margin-left:20px;">
</div>
</form>
```

My JavaScript file:

```
// JavaScript Document

//form validation
function validateForm() {

//name check
var name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
var nameLength = name.length; //get length of string stored in name

//email - ref http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp
var email = document.getElementById("usremail").value; 
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");  //gets position of the @ symbol in the string
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf("."); //gets position of the last dot in the string

//message - same method as name validation
var message = document.getElementById("comments").value; 
var messageLength = message.length;

if (name.length < 3)
{
    alert("Make sure all fields are filled in correctly");
    return false;

    }

    else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+ 2 >= email.length) 
        {                               
            alert("Make sure all fields are filled in correctly");
        return false;

        }

    else if (messageLength < 20)
    {
    alert("Make sure all fields are filled in correctly");
    return false;

    }
    else {

    return true;
    }

    }
```

The problem is when I run the code and submit the form - no matter what I input - nothing happens.

Comment: There are many, many questions covering how to achieve something like this.

Comment: Your HTML does not show the opening `<form>` tag, but if you didn't put something like `onsubmit=validateForm()` in it, that might explain why nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function but I cannot see that you are calling it anywhere. You need to call it by changing the corresponding HTML code to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" onclick="validateForm()" style="margin-left:100px;">
```

Comment: I would rather put the handler on the form submit event, so that you can more easily cancel validation on error.

Answer (score 0):

First, add *onClick="function();"* to your code.

If you want to get data by name, use getElement**s**ByName("tagname");

Note that the function returns an **array**. (Because you can add many inputs with the same name, that's why there's **Elements**).

Working Fiddle `[http://jsfiddle.net/pdp44fx4/2/][1]`

I couldn't paste it as a link, sorry.